# iOS - app works on device but not on simulator (anymore)

Tags: ios, xcode

I know already that there are topics like that, but nothing helped in my case ...

Here the info:

The app worked both on simulator and device the whole time.
I renamed the project recently into another name. Still worked both fine.
Today I realized that it didn't change the folder name and then it couldn't run anymore because it had somewhere the location saved from before. Then I gave the folder the old name again and it could build and run it on the device again. But weirdly enough it doesn't run on the simulator anymore.

Funny thing is also that it said that the profiles were expiring, which weren't even related to that project so I deleted them. No errors, nothing. It just builds and directly finishes on the simulator.

The app is build for iOS6 and doesn't support earlier versions. So it can't be the armv6 armv7 architecture problem ...

What I also tried is the following: I zip every bigger version change and save it on an external HD (in case anything dies) and also have it uploaded at bitbucket. I reset my project to those old working versions and it neither ran on the Simulator.

Thanks in advance for further tips!

Comment: Did you tried to remove the app on the simulator first and then re-install it by debugging in Xcode?

Comment: No, I didn't and apparently I can't even go to home on the simulator. So I guess the simulator is the problem. I will investigate further. That brings me already a lot further :)

Comment: So stupid... I was looking for hours in the settings of xcode and never figured it could be the simulator :') I simply reset it now and it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Make sure you or @Hailei writes an answer detailing the fix and then marks it as correct so the question isn't left marked unsolved.

Comment: Yea I know. I was waiting for Hailei to do it, since he actually gave the correct answer :p

Comment: @oxygen Thank you for waiting me to do it, the answer is there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem should be in your simulator but not necessarily in your app. Please have a try to:

1. reset the simulator and retry
2. if it still doesn't work, remove the app on simulator and re-install it via Xcode debugging